# curosr points to middle of text area instead of start

Tags: html, textarea

I have  a text area.

```
   <label for="add_note">Notes</label>
        <textarea name="notes"rows="2" cols="70"><?php if(!empty($this->notes)){ echo $this->notes; } ?> 
</textarea>
```

strangely when i hit tab or click on the text area cursor goes to center of the text area instead of beginning of text area..is it my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove spaces or Try with :-

```
<label for="add_note">Notes</label>
<textarea name="notes"rows="2" cols="70"><?php if(trim($this->notes)!=''){ echo this->notes; } ?></textarea>
```